# how to assign json strings from same dataset to different variables

Tags: javascript, json

I have a data set which has a number of devices with similar properties (output). (for example 2 given below). what I do not understand is how do I take each device with the new name and assign it to for example a new div. There can be many devices in dataset. How do I tell my code to whenever there is a new device take out bytes_read and bytes_written and assign them to a new div for example assign

```
"bdev0": {"Bytes_Read": 0,   "Bytes_Written": 0} to div_one 
"bdev1": {"Bytes_Read": 10, "Bytes_Written": 20  } to div_two
```

Note that I cannot use something like data.devices[0] because there are many devices and their names keep changing, e.g bdev0, bdev1, bdev2, bde3.. 
here is the sample of dataset given:

```
 var data = {
        "devices": [
            {
                "Name": "bdev0",
                "output": {
                    "IO_Operations": 0,
                    "Bytes_Read": 0,
                    "Bytes_Written": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "bdev1",
                "output": {
                    "IO_Operations": 10,
                    "Bytes_Read": 20,
                    "Bytes_Written": 30
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

This is how far I could come but it creates two different strings but how do I assign these separately to two different items. it sounds really stupid but I am really stuck here if for example I want to assign these strings to var a and var b how should I do it

```
        function myData() {
                for (var i in data.devices){
                       var obj = new Object();
                       obj.Bytes_read = data.devices[i].output.Bytes_Read;
                        obj.Bytes_written  = data.devices[i].output.Bytes_Written;
                         var jsonString= JSON.stringify(obj);
                   console.log(jsonString)
                  }
                }

    myData(data)
```

Result

```
 {"Bytes_read":0,"Bytes_written":0}
    {"Bytes_read":20,"Bytes_written":30}
```

It gives me the data I want but I cannot figure out to assign these sets to var a and var b.

Comment: Are you going to receive those datas synchronously or asynchronously? Also, is the amount of data previously known or unknown?

Comment: asynchronously and the amount is unknown

Comment: But do you need every data to be processed, or just specific parts of it? i.e., can `bdev0` and `bdev4` be relevant, but anything else to be irrelevant?

Comment: there is nothing else in the data, there are only names of devices e.g bdev0 bdev5 and their outputs so I think I need to process all data

Answer (score 2):

If you have the name of the device you can use it as key for the access of the data.

```js
var data = {
        "devices": [{
            "Name": "bdev0",
            "output": {
                "IO_Operations": 0,
                "Bytes_Read": 0,
                "Bytes_Written": 0
            }
        }, {
            "Name": "bdev1",
            "output": {
                "IO_Operations": 10,
                "Bytes_Read": 20,
                "Bytes_Written": 30
            }
        }]
    },
    selectedData = {};

data.devices.forEach(function (a) {
    selectedData[a.Name] = {
        Bytes_Read: a.output.Bytes_Read,
        Bytes_Written: a.output.Bytes_Written
    };
});
document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(selectedData, 0, 4)+'</pre>');
```

Update: Maybe this is what you want. With the name of the device, the function `getDeviceInfo` returns the information.

```js
function getDeviceInfo(deviceName) {
    var obj = {};
    data.devices.some(function (a) {
        if (a.Name === deviceName) {
            obj[deviceName] = {
                Bytes_Read: a.output.Bytes_Read,
                Bytes_Written: a.output.Bytes_Written
            };
            return true;
        }
    });
    return obj;
}

var data = {
        "devices": [{
            "Name": "bdev0",
            "output": {
                "IO_Operations": 0,
                "Bytes_Read": 0,
                "Bytes_Written": 0
            }
        }, {
            "Name": "bdev1",
            "output": {
                "IO_Operations": 10,
                "Bytes_Read": 20,
                "Bytes_Written": 30
            }
        }]
    },
    div_one = getDeviceInfo('bdev0'),
    div_two = getDeviceInfo('bdev1');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(div_one, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(div_two, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: yes but what I do not understand is how do I take each device with the new name and assign it to for example a new div. There can be many devices in dataset. How do I tell my code to whenever there is a new device take out bytes_read and bytes_written and assign them to a new div

Comment: @Imo, from where do you know, what name is important? where do you get the name (like `bdev0` or `bdev1`) from?

Comment: these are coming from a vm and the data is uniform all it has are json objects like the one in the dataset, every property with Name is important

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. The code below will take the `output` property of each element in array and set `a` to its value when `Name` is `bdev0`, and `b` to it otherwise. I hope this is what you needed:

```
var a, b;
if (data[0]['Name'] === 'bdev0') {
    a = JSON.stringify(data[0]['output']); // bdev0
    b = JSON.stringify(data[1]['output']); // bdev1
} else {
    a = JSON.stringify(data[1]['output']); // bdev1
    b = JSON.stringify(data[0]['output']); // bdev0
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question but what I am after is that each time there is a new 'Name' element, eg bdev1, bdev4 I can takeout its bytes_written and bytes_read properties and assign them to another variable. the actual dataset is exactly same as the sample data set but with many other devices

Comment: If you only need `Bytes_Read` and `Bytes_Written`, Nina's code should work for you.

Comment: unfortunately her answer does not answer my question perhaps I am not able to explain myself correctly. I just need a way to assign "bdev0": {"Bytes_Read": 0,   "Bytes_Written": 0} to div_one and "bdev1": {"Bytes_Read": 0, "Bytes_Written": 0  } to div_two